# How to stop mainActivity(rootTask) after startActivity();

Tags: java, android

My application is starting with MainActivity.Java that means this is root task.

And I have one more activity which is A.

I want to stop MainActivity(rootTask) when I go to lauch A activity with startActivity();

I do not want MainActivity to work until A class is exhausted.

finish(); is not working
Intent flags is not working
noHistory: is not working
startActivityForResult(intent, 0) is not working

What should I do ?

**EDİT**

MainActivity :

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

System.out.println("test");
```

In here, I want to wait. It should not display "test".

LoginActivity:

```
LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: What determines "A class being exhausted"?

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code
If you simply want to finish the current activity and start new activity do like this. finish must work.

```
startActivity(new Intent(CurrentAcitivity.this,NextActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.finish();
```

Comment: I edit my post @Ajay Shrestha. finish(); is not working because MainActivity is root.

Comment: I don't see you finish the MainActivity. There is no reason to doing that one
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: Nothing change when I delete them @Ajay Shrestha

Answer (score 0):

The [onStop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop()) method of `MainActivity` should be coded to stop the *thing* that you want to stop.

If you do that, then you should probably also put the logic for starting that *thing* in [onStart()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStart()).